# Where can I find better documentation for the CSS properties of GTK widgets?

Tags: css, gtk3

I'm working on learning the CSS styling part of GTK3, and I have noticed that the reference GTK documention talks about the CSS nodes that get created, but not what properties are valid for the component.

For instance, [GtkSeparator](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSeparator.html) includes this as the full CSS documentation:

> GtkSeparator has a single CSS node with name separator. The node gets one of the .horizontal or .vertical style classes.

This describes to me how to address this component in the stylesheet, but it took an hour of trial and error to figure out that the color for this component is controlled by the `background-color` attribute, not the `color` attribute.

I am having similar problems with [GtkComboBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBox.html) where the documentation lists the node hierarchy, but not what the nodes correspond to visually or what properties are valid for them.

Is there more detailed documentation for each component, especially listing valid properties and what the properties correspond to visually?

Comment: In CSS, `color` sets the color of the text, while `background-color` sets the color of the box itself. Documentation on CSS can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

Comment: @Celsiuss Your comment naively assumes that all CSS properties work in GTK, but they do not.

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. And at this point I've abandoned GTK. It's just too much effort to get anything that looks good, and I've had some recent bad experiences with GTK4.

Comment: What do you use instead? I need my app to go fullscreen on all monitors, which requires being closer to X11 than the browser is...

Comment: Experimenting with Tauri now. Haven't gone far into it, but it does fit with skills I already know from years of web and electron development.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the documentation.  They keep telling people to stop using GTK2, but until Gimp stops using it, it will be around for a while.  Lots of good books/documentation on GTK2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this:

https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-properties.html

I guess it is as accurate as the rest of the Gtk documentation...

Comment: I guess this is the best we get...

Comment: You mean, this is all those lazy programmers are willing to do.